# Usage of Perl to insert information to cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

So I need to transfer information from a file.  An example of the heading is label=1234 I was hoping I could use a perl code to change "label" to "id", is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Cy.js supports JSON data.  Convert or write your data to JSON, and you can load it in as described in the docs: http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/